# Add custom reponse header by using tomcat config only

Tags: apache, tomcat, header

I have a few tomcats load balanced behind a VIP(virtualIP) and Apache is configured to talk via AJP to the tomcat VIP. There is a need to know which tomcat served the request for debugging/monitoring purposes. And so the tomcat instance that served the request should ideally send a unique response header .
However I dont see how I can achieve that without writing custom filter code to do that. Ideally I want this unique header value to reside in tomcat conf/properties  folder. 
Any suggestions ?